# Combine sql rows into additional columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a database table 'stock_usage' that looks something like this.

```
id  |   item_id |   store_id    |   quantity    |   timestamp   
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is an `item` table and a `store` table. I'm creating a stock usage report in csv with the item in the first column and the rest representing a store each containing the total quantity used as below.

```
item_name   |   store_A |   store_B |   store_C |...
----------------------------------------------------
soap        |   3       |   4       |   5       |
```

My current solution is to retrieve the totals for each item per store as shown below and loop through the results in php to obtain the structure above.

```
item_name   |   store   |   quantity
------------------------------------
soap        |   store_A |   3
soap        |   store_B |   4
soap        |   store_C |   5
```

Is there a way to obtain this in sql without the additional code?

Comment: Please show your SQL code even if it doesn't work. And your version of Postgres.

Comment: How many stores do you have? three, four or dozens?

Comment: @Robert the number varies, but I can restrict the number of stores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, use `crosstab()` from the additional module `tablefunc` to pivot data. It's up for debate whether that's "native" or not.

Run once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

**However**, what you are trying to do is the opposite of a pivot function!

In **Postgres 9.4** or later use a `VALUES` expression in a `LATERAL` subquery to "unpivot":

```sql
SELECT s.item_name, t.*
FROM   stock_usage s
, LATERAL (
   VALUES
     ('store_A', s.store_a)
   , ('store_B', s.store_b)
   , ('store_C', s.store_c)
   ) t(year, count);
```

In **Postgres 9.3** or older (original answer) use [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html):

```sql
SELECT item_name, 'store_A'::text AS store, store_a AS quantity
FROM   stock_usage

UNION ALL
SELECT item_name, 'store_B'::text, store_b
FROM   stock_usage

UNION ALL
SELECT item_name, 'store_C'::text, store_c
FROM   stock_usage
;
```